# php update sql database

Tags: php, sql

updating SQL using PHP

The message to screen is:

```
object(mysqli)[1]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'client_info' => null
  public 'client_version' => null
  public 'connect_errno' => null
  public 'connect_error' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'host_info' => null
  public 'info' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'server_info' => null
  public 'server_version' => null
  public 'stat' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'protocol_version' => null
  public 'thread_id' => null
  public 'warning_count' => null
No rows updated
```

My code is:

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die(`Connect Error: ` . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
        echo `Successful connection to MySQL <br />`;

    $employ = $_POST['employer'];
    $address = $_POST['flat'];
    $login_name = $_POST['login_name'] ;
    var_dump($connection);

//    Insert employer and address into database row for logged in user.    

$query = "UPDATE members SET employer = `$employ`, flat = `$address` WHERE     login=`$login_name`";

if (!$result = $connection->query($query)) {
        echo "No rows updated <br />";
    } else {
            echo $result . " row(s) successfully updated<br />";
            }
    }



?>
```

The form I am getting the information from is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>



<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" >
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
</td>
</tr>

<td style="height:500px;width:400px; ">
<center>


<h2>Update</h2><br>


<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="login_name" value="$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN']">

<p>employer <input type="text" name="employer"> </p>
<p>flat number <input type="text" name="flat"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login" ></p>
</form>



</center>

</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I've been trying to get this to work for days.
The user logs into their profile and all of their information is then taken from the SQL database and then displayed onto the screen. The form above is to update their profile with specific information updating their row in the database for the next time they log in.

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Just curious ... did Marcel Korpel's suggestion resolve your issue? LOL

Comment: Hi @Marcel I'm not to worried about security at the moment as I am still learning and this wont actually go live. Thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP admin?

Comment: You *should* be worried about security! And these pages are seen by more people than just you and me; they might think this is a good example of programming a query.

Comment: The reason I ask is to eliminate the query from the code. Try mocking up the query in PHPAdmin and if that works, then you will know the problem resides in your code. If tha makes sense.

Comment: @Mike It's the database connection that goes wrong: see the dump after `@mysqli_connect`.

Comment: Ah, duh, I wasn't paying attention to the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "@" on your connect to see the error you get while connecting. as you see in your connection-object you don't habe a database-connection.

Comment: Still no luck in getting it working unfortunately! Is there anything obvious that I am missing/not aware of?

Comment: As long as your $connection-object only got NULLs you don't have a db-connection. You should first make sure about getting a working db-connection, so check your host/user/password/db. Take a empty php file and only include your database-connector. As I see now your if must be "if($connection->mysqli_connect_error()).